# How do I print something out according to a response in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm making a test program. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String pages;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Book #1
        // =1=

        Book anothermedium = new Book();
        anothermedium.title = "Another Medium";
        anothermedium.author = "Jen Smith";
        anothermedium.pages = "387";

        // Book #2
        // =2=

        Book whateveryouwant = new Book();
        whateveryouwant.title = "Whatever You Want";
        whateveryouwant.author = "Bob Gray";
        whateveryouwant.pages = "424";

        System.out.println("Enter the name of a book to see its details  ");
        System.out.println("or input Catalog to see the catalog.");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so when you input something like `Catalog` the response will be something like:

> The current catalog consists of the books:
>
> Another Medium
>
> Whatever You Want

I'm sorry if this has already been posted. I searched and I couldn't find anything addressing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if-statement,

```
if(input.toLowerCase().equals("catalog"){
   //do what you need to do here
   System.out.println("The current catalog consists of the books: ");
   System.out.println(anothermedium.title);
   System.out.println(whateveryouwant.title);
}
```

To make the condition case-sensitive, the input string should be converted to lowercase. If you don't understand the syntax, basically the condition in the if-statement gets evaluated. If if evaluates to true, then whatever's in between the brackets gets exectued. If it evaluates to false, then it skips whatever's in the two brackets to proceed with the rest of the code. Hope this is what you need. Good luck!

Comment: my bad forgot a pair of parentheses. check it out now

Comment: That sort of worked. Here's the code I put down:    http://pastebin.com/2kGnZydk When I type in Another Medium it works just fine, but it just loops with Whatever You Want.

Comment: you forgot a closing bracket } for the if statement checking if input is "another medium". So add a '}' after System.out.println("Number of pages:" +anothermedium.pages);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add each `Book` to a `List<Book>` that can looped over for the correct element, or can be used to print the entire catalogue. Something like the following implementation.

This way if you user wants a specific book the `else if()` can match the title and print the correct `Book` Otherwise if the user wants to view the enire catalogue they will only be shown the `Book Titles`

```
List<Book> listBook = new ArrayList<>();
listBook.add( whateveryouwant  );
listBook.add( anothermedium  );

System.out.println( "Enter the name of a book to see its details  " );
System.out.println( "or input Catalog to see the catalog." );
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
String input = scan.nextLine();

for( Book book : listBook )
{
    if( "catalog".equalsIgnoreCase( input ) )
    {
        System.out.println( "Title: " + book.getTitle() );
    }
    else if( book.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase( input ) )
    {
        System.out.println( book.toString() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an arrayList of these book objects. Add each objects of book in that list.Run this code it should work.

```
 public class Book {
private String title;
private String author;
private String pages;
public void Book(){
  }
 public String getTitle(){
     return title;
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Book #1
    // =1=
    ArrayList<Book> catalog = new ArrayList<Book>();

    Book anothermedium = new Book();
    anothermedium.title = "Another Medium";
    anothermedium.author = "Jen Smith";
    anothermedium.pages = "387";
    catalog.add(anothermedium);
    // Book #2
    // =2=

    Book whateveryouwant = new Book();
    whateveryouwant.title = "Whatever You Want";
    whateveryouwant.author = "Bob Gray";
    whateveryouwant.pages = "424";
    catalog.add(whateveryouwant);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of a book to see its details");
    System.out.println("or input Catalog to see the catalog.");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("catalog"))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<catalog.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(catalog.get(i).getTitle());
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different problems you're trying to solve here.

1. How do I conditionally display a certain output, based on the
   user's input text?
2. How do I iterate over the contents of a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and display their names?

One thing to keep in mind is that Java is Object-Oriented. You almost always want to consider the problem you're trying to solve, and create classes that represent the various types of things within your problem space. You've described a `Book` entity and a `Catalog` entity in this case. These are usually separate classes from your main program class (that contains your `main` method).

You can solve the first problem by using an [`if`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) statement to compare the input to a constant that your application knows about. You can solve the next problem by defining meaningful classes around your problem structure, and defining `toString` methods with the output that you want to see.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CatalogViewer {

    private static final String VIEW_CATALOG_KEY = "catalog";

    public static class Book {
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private String pages;

        public Book(String title, String author, String pages) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.pages = pages;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public static class Catalog {
        private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        public List<Book> getBooks() {
            return books;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

            message.append("The current catalog consists of the books:\n");

            for (Book book : books) {
                message.append("\n" + book + "\n");
            }

            return message.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Catalog catalog = new Catalog();

        catalog.getBooks().add(new Book("Another Medium", "Jen Smith", "387"));
        catalog.getBooks().add(new Book("Whatever You Want", "Bob Gray", "424"));

        System.out.println("Enter the name of a book to see its details  ");
        System.out.println("or input Catalog to see the catalog.");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        if (input.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(VIEW_CATALOG_KEY)) {
            System.out.println(catalog);
        }
    }
}
```